# Overall variance of a Dirichlet distribution

Tags: variance, dirichlet-distribution

I have observations on proportion of individuals at different age groups. I'm doing some simulation experiments, and I need to introduce error in the observed data. For that, I'm simulating data from my original observations using a Dirichlet distribution.
I'm able to simulate the data and to calculate the variance of each age group, where

$ V(p_i)=\frac{a_i(A-a_i)}{A^2(1+A)}$

However, I need to get the variance of the overall distribution, i.e. all age groups combined. My question is: how much does this new distribution deviates on overall from the original one?
The shape parameter dictates how much the generated distribution deviates from the original one (when the shape parameter is large, p is likely to be near the mean, and when it is small, p is distributed more diffusely), but it is not clear to me how to set the shape parameter so that the standard deviation of all ages combined would be around a certain value, or to introduce a specific amount of error in my data.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Val

Comment: Please explain to us what "variability from" and the "overall variance" of this multivariate distribution might be.

Comment: Hello @whuber. I modified the question, hopefully it is clearer now. Thanks for that.

Comment: Thank you, but your meaning is still obscure: what exactly would be the "variance of ... all age groups combined"?  One natural interpretation is to add the counts of all age groups, but (presumably) that's a constant and so its variance is zero.  Often a good way to proceed is to consider how you originally obtained the data, because that will suggest how to model their variability -- but having (as yet) no information about that, we can't help formulate a good answer.